# The InputConnection class doesn't work correctly on Huawei phones

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

When I press a button on the keyboard, the current visible text inside the textview is replaced by the last key pressed (and not added as I expected). That is, if I try to enter "12" when I press "1", everything will be fine, when I press "2", the old character "1" will be replaced by "2". The problem occurs only on Huawei smartphones, everything works fine on the rest. I add the text as follows: inputConnection.commitText(inputedCharacter.toString(), 1). What's wrong with Huawei ?

Comment: hi@ProcgerXacker,  we are very sorry that it brings you inconvinience and are now investigating the root cause of it. Could you kindly help us with some information to locate this issue? 1.The device model on which this issue happened. 2. The device‘s ROM version, and what input method do you use?

Comment: And it would be great if you could provide a screen recording recorded during the appearance of this.

Comment: @shirley , I tried it on Honor 8x, Huawei P20, Honor 20 Lite. I assume that the problem is not in a specific phone, but in the Huawei and Honor operation system. 
I use the InputConnection interface and the commitText method. It is noteworthy that when debugging, when I put the breakpoint on commitText, everything works fine.